# How to handle multiple submission/post request in .NET API?

Tags: .net, angular, asp.net-core

These days separate API(.NET Core) and separate Client(using angular/react) is very common. Basically how we do it is like offering a server-side API and a JS-based client to communicate with the API. In many cases, we need to perform post request/form submission. In angular, after clicking submit button the framework performs a post request to the API. Multiple submit click will trigger multiple post requests. Not only that, if we try to consume the API using tools like postman, we can perform post requests many times. So, the question is, using what kind of mechanism we can limit this duplicate submission/post request from backend/API in .NET without affecting the performance?

Comment: You can handle the model appropriately if there are nested forms. As an example, submit all data from all forms at once. If all of the forms are distinct, you'll have to send the data from each one independently. Both are effective methods for submitting and performing.

Comment: To perform a distinct check I have to go to the database which is not efficient enough in my view. Restricting duplicate submission is a very basic requirement for a system and to me, it seems API architecture has drawback on it.

Comment: I agree with @Girish, in front-end, we can disable the submit button before the callback, and in server side, we can add middleware or something else to set rate limit, or using api gateway such as azure api management.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution from client side is disable the submit button once the submit is triggered.

But that leaves space for too many calls from other clients (postman/thunderbolt etc.) or a DDoS attack. More solid architecture in that case you can build is by using 'API Rate Limiter'.

One nice blog to get started : https://blog.elmah.io/rate-limiting-api-requests-with-asp-net-core-and-aspnetcoreratelimit/

Edit:
To prevent duplicate resource creation you can put a 'unique' constraint for entity. (Anyway without checking in db you won't be able to know whether same thing is already there)